# Why do I get an error when trying to `read` this value?

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

The .hs code :

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String  
                     , lastName :: String  
                     , age :: Int  
                     } deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

Compilation :

```
*Main> :load "/home/optimight/baby.hs"  
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/optimight/baby.hs, interpreted )  
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

While testing immediately after compilation:

```
*Main> read "Person {firstName = \"Michael\", lastName \"Diamond\", age = 43}" :: Person  
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Please guide. Why this error is occurring and how to avoid such errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lastName \"Diamond\"
```

is missing an equals sign.

```
read "Person {firstName = \"Michael\", lastName = \"Diamond\", age = 43}" :: Person
```

Comment: Sir, removed the error. The code is working now. Sorry, took your time for such small thing.

Comment: No problem, didn't take much time. Since it wasn't mine, the typo jumped out quickly. As for "how to avoid such errors?", there is unfortunately no way, you will always make typos, like everybody else.

Comment: Sir, I am encouraged (to learn more quickly) by your warm response. Thanks a lot.